# Convert texture data to... vertex data?

Tags: opengl, copy, textures, buffer

I need some clarifications about a paragraph of this wiki page:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Buffer_Object_Usage

> COPY is used when a buffer object is used to pass data from one place in OpenGL to another. For example, **you can read image data into a buffer, then use that image data as vertex data in a draw call.** [...]

Does that mean that I can theoretically byte-by-byte copy data from a conventional 2D texture into a VBO? How do I do this? That may come in handy.

Comment: No, that is not what it means. There are Texture Buffer Objects in GL3.0, those are the only ones that allow you to use texture image data as a buffer object. Now, the interesting thing about buffer objects is they are actually typeless. A "VBO" can be used as a "TBO" provided their memory is laid out in a way where such a thing even makes sense.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Probably not in the form of TBOs. You can use PBO pack/unpack buffers instead. Take a GL_TEXTURE_2D, put its contents in a PBO and do the copy. How does it sound now?

Comment: Still sounds incorrect to me, because if you used a PBO you would not necessarily be doing a direct byte-by-byte copy. That is because PBOs encapsulate the pixel transfer part of the API, which includes accommodation for data / format conversion. If you guarantee the data type, format, number of components and alignment match then you could do a byte-by-byte copy, but otherwise the driver may have to do extra processing to make this possible. Texture Buffer Objects are really your best bet for exposing the data stored in a conventional texture for direct-copy semantics into a buffer object.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman So are you implying that there is a way I'm not aware of to convert a texture_2d into a TBO? That would be interesting too. As a side note, nowadays textures are likely to be managed with float components (a float for red, another float for green etc...) so as far as the texture is made up of GL_FLOATs, the PBO is GL_FLOATs too, and, of course, the target VBO is GL_FLOATs, there should be nothing in my way that forbids me in doing the trick without prohibitive driver overhead.

Comment: No they're not. Textures are generally 8-bit unsigned normalized fixed-point. GPUs are designed to do fixed-point -> floating-point conversion when you sample these textures. But deep down, they are generally 8-bit per-component. To that end, if you had an RGB internal format, the actual stored data is probably RGBx (for alignment). If you tried to read the texture back as RGB, the driver could not do a direct copy because there is one extra padded component that it has to discard. As for 2D textures, no a TBO is 1D, but they do allow you to store vertex data in a texture trivially.

Comment: Managing textures using floating-point components is a massive waste of memory. Even HDR textures are often something like fixed-point RGBA 10:10:10:2, or in some cases half-float but not often full float.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ok, I acknowledge that a big amount of memory is needed, but you indeed _can_ initialize a texture to use 32bit floats per component. Thus, to me it _is_ feasible to do the steps `2Dtex -> PBO -> VBO` without additional conversions. Leaving aside the memory consumption, can you confirm this? Last thing, I would know more about turning a 2Dtex into a TBO, as you mentioned (for "exposing the data").

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Make sure you use a 4-component vertex format for proper data alignment. Why do you need to store vertex data in a 2D texture though? The maximum dimensions of a 2D texture can be a little restrictive if you need a lot of vertices; TBOs are 1 dimensional but they have larger dimensions compared to traditional textures (65,536 is the minimum dimension, but many implementations support 4x the total capacity using a TBO instead of a 2D texture). You will, of course, have to sample them using `texelFetch (...)`. They are basically a primitive form of Shader Storage Buffers.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I don't "need" that. I was just curious about how one can convert buffers around in hardware. Thank you for the very useful insights.